# Why is Area 51 listed on my combined flair if I don't have 200 reputation on it?

Tags: support, reputation, area-51, flair, combined-flair

Here is a picture of how my combined flair looks at the moment I'm posting this:

[image]

As you can see, Area 51 is listed on my flair. The strange thing is that on Area 51, I currently only have 156 reputation (and have never had more), and only sites where I have 200 or more reputation are supposed to show up on the flair, as stated on the [flair page](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=flair):

> (please note that only sites where you have more than 200 reputation will appear, and that flair is only updated once every 24-36 hours.)

Is this a bug? Is it a feature specific to Area 51? Is there any other reason why it's like this?

If this is a bug, please fix it and retag my question to [bug](/questions/tagged/bug). If it's intentional, please explain the exact conditions for which this happens and the reason behind it.

**Edit:**

Just to clarify, I'm *not* asking why sites where I have less than 200 reputation count in the total reputation displayed on the flair. I'm asking why the Area 51 *icon* is displayed on my flair.

Comment: @DavidPostill No, the other question is asking why sites where the user has 101 reputation count in the total number of reputation. I'm asking why the icon is present on the flair.

Comment: It's the same bug.@DonaldDuck